# Liquid: Print All Possible Outputs of an `If` or `Case` tag

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, liquid

I'm wondering if there's any way to display all the possible outputs of either an `If` tag or a `case` tag, in Liquid. I'd like to be able to display the outputs for editing / debugging purposes.

For example, given:

```
{% assign foo = allCases %}

{% case foo %}
 {% when 1 %}
  This is the case when foo is 1.
 {% when 2 %}
  This is the case when foo is 2.
{% endcase %}
```

Where `allCases` is a value so that the output would be:

> This is the case when foo is 1.
>
> This is the case when foo is 2.

N.B. while I used a special value for `foo` to illustrate the desired output, maybe it could be achieved with a filter, instead? e.g. `[% case foo | showAll %]`?

---

### Attempted Solution:

I thought that the multi-case support might allow for this, so tried:

```
{% assign foo = 0 %}

{% case foo %}
 {% when 1, 0 %}
  This is the case when foo is 1 or 0.
 {% when 2, 0 %}
  This is the case when foo is 2 or 0.
{% endcase %}
```

However, this only returns

> This is the case when foo is 1 or 0.

*i.e.* it goes through the cases until it reaches the first matching case and then stops evaluating other cases. `If` tags have the same behaviour.

**I know this could be achieved using separate if-statements**, but was hoping to find a solution that didn't multiply the number of tags, in this way, as it is just for editing / debugging purposes, but is not needed for the final code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for debugging purpose you might try this:

```
{% for i in (0..3) %} 
    {% case forloop.index %}
    {% when 1 or 0 %}
        This is the case when index is 1 or 0.
    {% when 2 %}
        This is the case when index is 2. 
    {% else %} 
        Others
    {% endcase %}
{% endfor %}
```

The loop allows to you to artificially fulfill all cases.